# index out of range in Numbers list

Tags: python

I am learning the basics of python, and trying to solve the above mentioned problem. However, I got stuck at this point: when I'm revising the code, everything seems OK to me, but I get an error:

```
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
  File "/tmp/vmuser_tmqtokdyaa/main.py", line 25, in numbers_in_lists
    while int(string[i]) <= prev:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I did revise other threads with the same IndexError problem, but it didn't quite solve my situation here. Any clues? Thank you in advance.

Here goes the task:

*Numbers in lists by SeanMc from forums
define a procedure that takes in a string of numbers from 1-9 and
outputs a list with the following parameters:
Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.
If a number x in the string is less than or equal 
to the preceding number y, the number x should be inserted 
into a sublist. Continue adding the following numbers to the 
sublist until reaching a number z that
is greater than the number y. 
Then add this number z to the normal list and continue.*

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    i=0
    prev = 0
    list = []
    sublist = []
    while i< len(string):
        if int(string[i]) > prev:
            list.append(string[i])
            prev = int(string[i])
            i +=1
        else:
            while int(string[i]) <= prev:
                sublist.append(string[i])
                i +=1
            list.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
    return list

#testcases
string = '543987'
result = [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]]
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
string= '987654321'
result = [9,[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
string = '455532123266'
result = [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
string = '123456789'
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because in this inner `while`, where you get the error, you don't check if `i < len(str)` and you keep incrementing, checking only condition unrelated to this problem, ignoring if you've reached last character of a string or not.
I would change it to:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    i=0
    prev = 0
    list = []
    sublist = []
    while i< len(string):
        if int(string[i]) > prev:
            list.append(string[i])
            prev = int(string[i])
            i +=1
        else:
            while  i< len(string) and int(string[i]) <= prev:
                sublist.append(string[i])
                i +=1
            list.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
    return list
```

And I would consider using for loop instead of while in your case, but above works anyway.

Comment: How would you propose to solve it? Is it possible to add just one or two lines and maintain the original code more or less?
I tried different solutions, such as:
- changing the name of the variable "i" just for this small loop so it doesn't get confused with the original "i" used in the first loop:
else:
            b = i
            while int(string[b]) <= prev:
                sublist.append(string[b])
                b +=1
            list.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
            i = b

Comment: I added simple solution. I didn't check if it works as intendet though, but it solves the error.

Comment: I tried that too, but it still spits out the error, as if it just didn't comply with the statement 'int(string[i])<=prev' no matter what you do

Comment: Well that's weird, because it works for me and I don't get any errors...

Comment: Are you sure you've tried the exact thing? It's important that you first check if i< len(string) before int(string[i]) <= prev

Comment: Ok, my bad, works now. Thanks a lot for help! Could you just explain why the order of conditions in the small while loop is important?

Comment: Because if first condition is false, then interpreter doesn't check the second one (because one false is enough to make the whole phrase false) - so when i is not < len(string) it doesn't even try to get string[i]. Other way round it would first try string[i] before checking if i < len(string)